Azure service bus repeat call
I know this may be a trivial question, but I'm not sure what to do. I am using Azure Service Bus together with MassTransit.
I have two services. Service1 is a WebApi application, and Service2 is a couple of Azure Functions units that respond to service bus topics.
In Service1 I have a consumer for the TestMessage topic. If I notify the topic, it passes to the consumer fine. But when an exception occurs inside the consumer it is immediately notified by the Fault consumer.
Config:
services.AddMassTransit(o =>
{
    o.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    o.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        var connectionStrings = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConnectionStringOption>>();

        cfg.Host(new HostSettings
        {
            ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://" + connectionStrings.Value.Messaging),
            TokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential()
        });
        
        cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<TestMessage>(formatter.Consumer<TestMessageConsumer>(), e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<TestMessageConsumer>(context);
        });

        cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<Fault<TestMessage>>(formatter.Consumer<TestMessageFaultConsumer>(), e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<TestMessageFaultConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});

Consumer:
public class TestMessageConsumer : IConsumer<TestMessage>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestMessage> context)
    {
        throw new Exception();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class TestMessageFaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<TestMessage>>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<TestMessage>> context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

However, if I send a message to the Azure Function in Service2 and an exception occurs, the call is repeated until the max delivery count (10) is reached. The Fault consumer in Service1 is then called that many times.
Config in service1:
        if (!await adminClient.TopicExistsAsync(formatter.MessageName<TestMessage>()))
            await adminClient.CreateTopicAsync(new CreateTopicOptions(formatter.MessageName<TestMessage>()));
        if (!await adminClient.SubscriptionExistsAsync(formatter.MessageName<TestMessage>(), formatterCheckFunc.ConsumerFromMessageName<TestMessageConsumer>()))
            await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(new CreateSubscriptionOptions(formatter.MessageName<TestMessage>(), formatterCheckFunc.ConsumerFromMessageName<TestMessageConsumer>()));

Config in serivce2:
        services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumer<TestMessageConsumer>();
        }, "ServiceBusConnection", (context, configuration) =>
        {
            var connectionStrings = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConnectionStringOption>>();

            var settings = new HostSettings
            {
                ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://" + connectionStrings.Value.Messaging),
                TokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(),
            };

            configuration.Host(settings);
        });

Function:
    public Function(IMessageReceiver receiver)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Function(nameof(Function))]
    
    public async Task Run([Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ServiceBusTrigger(TopicName, SubscriptionName, Connection = Connection)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {          
        await _receiver.HandleConsumer<TestMessageConsumer>(TopicName, SubscriptionName, message, cancellationToken);
    }

I guess it's not entirely clear to me the reason why it's being called like this multiple times and I don't really know what to do about it. I would expect that if I get a message and it falls into exception, the call is no longer made, because if it runs 10 times, I don't know if I can duplicate the data in the db etc. It makes sense to me that it will run 10 times if the Azure function is unavailable, the message gets lost over the network, etc.

The issue where messages processed by your Azure Function are being retried multiple times upon encountering an exception, leading to multiple calls to the Fault consumer in Service1. To handle it we can use the message handling behavior to limit the number of retries or specify a retry policy .
services.AddMassTransit(o =>
{
    o.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    o.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        var connectionStrings = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConnectionStringOption>>();

        cfg.Host(new HostSettings
        {
            ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://" + connectionStrings.Value.Messaging),
            TokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential()
        });
        
        cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<TestMessage>(formatter.Consumer<TestMessageConsumer>(), e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<TestMessageConsumer>(context);

            // Configure retry policy if needed
            e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))); // Example retry policy: 3 retries with 5 seconds interval
        });

        cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<Fault<TestMessage>>(formatter.Consumer<TestMessageFaultConsumer>(), e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<TestMessageFaultConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});



In Azure Function Function class you should handle exceptions and the message to prevent it from being retried.

ServiceBusReceiver.AbandonMessageAsync Method Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception or handle it appropriately
        // If processing failed due to an unrecoverable error, abandon the message
        await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
    }
}



This didn't help anyway it runs twice. However, the way you describe the try catch, I think that's the right idea. But by using the AbandonMessageAsync method, you're telling the message to just try sending again. I think it should be more like Complete or ToDlq (but that doesn't feel right to me) even then it falls into the error queue.

Have you tried with e.UseMessageRetry

Yes. But its still running two times.

what is  r.Interval you used

I've tried various like 3, 5 and 1.

with 1 how many times it's running
